# format the shell script output as a table

Tags: shell, scripting, text-formatting

I am running a script in a loop which creates some data as per some logic and then displays output in some combination but the output I am getting is in new line

```
Roll number               : 187437366 
Mobile Number             : 07995036927
Grade                     : A
Roll number               : 187437367 
Mobile Number             : 07995036937
Grade                     : B
```

However I want output in a tabular format something like below -

```
Roll Number | Mobile Number | Grade
187437366   | 07995036927   | A
187437466   | 07995037922   | A2
187437266   | 07995036921   | B
187437766   | 07995036120   | C
```

I am unable to find a concept on how to achieve this...can someone help me please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix it such that the provided expected output is exactly what you'd expect given the provided sample input.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is not the only tool in the toolbox, of course.  Just to counterbalance the inevitable deluge of `awk` scripts, here's [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html) in action:

```
% mlr --ixtab --ips : --opprint cat << END
Roll number               : 187437366
Mobile Number             : 07995036927
Grade                     : A

Roll number               : 187437367
Mobile Number             : 07995036937
Grade                     : B

END
Roll number                Mobile Number              Grade
 187437366                  07995036927                A
 187437367                  07995036937                B
%
```

Just make your script emit a blank line after every record, or add in an intermediary filter that does that, and what you have is in the "XTAB" input format, with `:` as the "pair separator" character (c.f. the `--ixtab` and `--ips` options).

The aforegiven is the "PPRINT" output format.  For output more like the question, there's a `--barred` option for "PPRINT" and a "Markdown" alternative output format with `--omd`.  However, I do not have a recent version of Miller immediately to hand for demonstration.

Comment: FWIW, just so we're comparing apples to apples and in case it is an option: If there **were** a blank line between every iteration then there would be a much briefer/simpler awk solution possible too by putting awk in paragraph mode with `RS=""` and using `FS="[:\n]"` as the field separator. Then every odd numbered field is the header string and every even numbered one is the associated value.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
$ awk -F':' '{printf "%s%s", $2, (/^Grade/)?"\n":"\t|"}' file
```

Output:

```
 187437366      | 07995036927   | A
 187437367      | 07995036937   | B
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and tabs and `|` as separators:

```
awk -F: '
  BEGIN{ printf "%s\t|%s\t|%s","Roll Number","Mobile Number","Grade"}
  { gsub(/ /,"",$2); printf "%s", ($1 ~ "^Roll" ? RS : "\t|") $2 }
  END { print "" }
' file
```

In the `BEGIN` block, print the header using a tab and `|` between each field.
Then remove all space characters from the second field (leading and trailing) and

1. if the first field begins with `Roll`, add a record separator `RS` (newline), otherwise print a tab and `|`
2. print the second field

In the `END` block, print another newline.

Output:

```
Roll Number     |Mobile Number  |Grade
187437366       |07995036927    |A
187437367       |07995036937    |B
```

Comment: Hi,

I am getting output like below

Roll Number      |Mobile Number     |Grades     |187437435

07410000911     |A         |187437436

07410000912     |A+        |187437437

07410000913     |B

Comment: It's hard to read output from the comments. Are you sure your input file is a unix text file and doesn't contain carriage returns? Do you get the same output if you run `dos2unix file` and run the command again?

Answer (score 0):

Without coupling your code to any of the data values in your input file and instead just relying on your header values repeating:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"
    OFS = "|"
}
seen[$1]++ { prt() }
{
    hdrs[++numFlds] = $1
    vals[numFlds] = $2
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   fldNr) {
    if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
        for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", hdrs[fldNr], (fldNr<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", vals[fldNr], (fldNr<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    numFlds = 0
    delete seen
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s'|' -o' | ' -t
Roll number | Mobile Number | Grade
187437366   | 07995036927   | A
187437367   | 07995036937   | B
```